# Ubuntu freeze on shutdown, restart, logout

Tags: 16.04

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I am unable to successfully shutdown, restart or logout without using the physical power button on my laptop.

I've just made a partition on my laptop to dual boot ubuntu 16.04 LST alongside windows 10. At the completion of the installation process, I was prompted to restart my PC. Upon clicking the "Restart Now" button, my cursor disappears, everything stops responding and the screen stays frozen indefinitely. (See pic)

[image: Image1]

Additionally, after forcing the restart via the physical power button, if I ever try to shutdown, restart or logout (even via the command line) my cursor will again disappear, everything stops responding and the screen remains frozen indefinitely. (See pic)

[image: Image 2]

Excluding this issue, the ubuntu installation works perfectly.

Does anybody know why I am experiencing this issue and/or how I can fix it?

Comment: Well, all of those involve logging out, though I'm not sure why it freezes.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex This issue also occurs at the login screen (before I log in) if I try to shut down or restart. So the problem may not be tied directly to logging out